# How can I make an HTTP GET request with Perl?

Tags: perl, http, http-get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make an HTTP GET request from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556724/how-can-i-make-an-http-get-request-from-perl)

I am trying to retrieve the entire source of an HTML page through perl so I can parse some data from it later on.

What is the easiest way to do so?

(by easiest I mean least overhead of adding new libraries)

Thanks

Comment: It helps if you show us what you tried?

Comment: tried some webscrapers linked by some question on thy were all too specific to retrieve something pre-set from the webpage. I want something more generic

Comment: There **is** a FAQ: http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-fetch-an-HTML-file-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP%3a%3aSimple) is a great way to connect to websites to get source info.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.example.com';
my $content = get $url or die "Unable to get $url\n";
print $content;
```